# How to save initial CGContextRef

Tags: ios, pdf, frame, cgcontext

I'm displaying a PDF page inside a `UIScrollView`. I started using http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04/presenting-pdf-files-by-yourself/ article as background.

When it comes to zooming I want to do the following thing to avoid blurring results.

When I open the view the zoom scale is 1.0. Now, I want to store somehow the corresponding `CGContextRef` according to this view which is shown on the whole screen.

Then I always want to scale the corresponding Quartz coordinate system by the zoom scale of the scrollView and finally transform coordinate system to the right place and make the frame larger/smaller corresponding to the scroll view zoom scale.

But I don't know how to save the initial `CGContextRef` and reload it every time in the drawRect method.

Can somebody help me with that? Or does somebody know how to scale the PDF page properly? Because, when I zoom in or out, the view's frame gets changed and the graphical context always lies within this frame. So I double scale everything (first the frame and then the PDF document within the frame). Hence I need to scale the PDF when the frame covers the whole screen (initial case).

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Can you show your source code (only the relevat parts) and some pictures (not necessarily here, a link to some website is sufficient) of the original pdf and the zoomed result?

Comment: @ott-- Hi, I added a detailed problem description now above. Every help is appreciated ;-)